# The daily quota requested by Google Place API is 1 and cannot be modified. How to increase the quota

Tags: google-places-api

The daily quota requested by Google Place API is 1 and cannot be modified. How to increase the quota

I tried to delete the project and rebind the settlement method, but there was no quota limit, but a few days later, a daily quota limit request appeared

Comment: This could be a billing related issue. You should file a support case so that an agent can take a look at your account. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support